# How To: Kinetic.js cached shape filter

Tags: javascript, html, caching, filter, kineticjs

Kinetic.js doc reference tells us following:

> cache node to improve drawing performance, **apply filters**, or create
>   more accurate hit regions

But when i try to cache custom shape and apply some filters to it as following

```
shape.cache();
shape.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Brighten]); //nothing happens
shape.filterBrightness(100); //this even throws error: Shape doesn't have this method at all
```

So is there any way to apply some sort of filter/shadow/blur/stroke to cached shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at documantation if you can't find some methods: http://kineticjs.com/docs/

```
rect.brightness(0.5);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fucix/1/edit

Comment: I look at the shape docs and even a node docs, but i didn't realize that i could find it in image docs (via google after your answer). Anyway thank you!